# How to disable ACL inheritance on folder for long path?

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke

I am trying to copy ACL(permissions) from source folder to destination. The folder path is a long path, so can't use .net inbuilt functions.

I am using `GetNamedSecurityInfo` to read ACl of source folder and `SetNamedSecurityInfo` to write ACL.

I want turn off ACL inheritance on destination to match source but `SetNamedSecurityInfo` always enable inheritance.

We can disable the inheritance for normal paths (not long path) using following .Net inbuilt methods. Please suggest some method of win32 COM API (pinvoke) to achieve same for long path.

```
DirectorySecurity dSecurityOut = System.IO.Directory.GetAccessControl(destinationNormalPath);
dSecurityOut.SetAccessRuleProtection(true,false);
System.IO.Directory.SetAccessControl(destinationNormalPath, dSecurityOut);
```